# MVC-bind simple html textbox without use of html helper and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have one question regarding MVC (I am new to MVC)
My question is

In MVC with Razor for textbox we write like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name)
```

Now suppose I don't want to use Razor and html helper class. I want
simple html input, like this

```
<input type="text" name='@Model.name' value='@Model.name'>
```

Is the above possible somehow?

Comment: karthik thanks for replay ,but i have try above but its not work.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you wouldn't want Model binding?  I ask since you say you are new to MVC, there may be a misconception.  To answer your question though, yes, you can just write HTML.  If the name attribute that you give it matches a property name in the model that the server accepts on its post back, then the binding would occur.  So you would do `<input type="text" name="name" value='@Model.name'/>`

Comment: Did you see any errors

Comment: what about it isnt working? maybe that you're naming the input after the value in name.

Comment: @DaveA that is exactly what would be happening.  I still don't understand his use case, but waiting for more info.

Comment: @Sagarpatel you cannot bind the way you have used in the post. Check out the comment from user(tostringtheory) which helps

Answer (score 13):

you can use

```
<input type="text" name='@Html.NameFor(x => x.name)' value='@Model.name'>
```